# How To Post a form data to server in sencha touch and ext js using the model or store provided

Tags: javascript, extjs, touch

How To Post a form data to server in sencha touch and ext js using the model or store provided. 
Basically using the proxy in store we read data from url and map it with the store.
How to do the same in reverse, like updating the server with certain data using some post request. Here in my post request will call a service in .net which is not the same to retrieve the details.

Comment: in what format are you posting? There is `store.sync()` method for the purpose you described.

Comment: for instance there are two fields name and id in my form... need to post it to server (ASP MVC services) using a web api url (post) as an ajax post request with params set as JSON.

Comment: have you tried http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sync